# Google Cloud SQL - MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying to setup a MySQL replication, but I'm a little bit confused considering my current setup:

Basically, I have a bunch of remote MySQL servers. All servers should be considered "masters" and none of those have a static ip address. I want to replicate those servers to the Google Cloud Plataform, so I can have a backup replica with - at least - read access.

Is there a way to setup each one of the remote MySQL servers to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance and stay in sync? Would you recommend a different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your post what you mean by "All Servers should be considered 'masters'", but Cloud SQL doesn't support Multi-Master setups.

You can use Cloud SQL to [replicate from a single external master](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external). (You can [get an overview of replication options here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/).)

However, you will likely need to make your database accessible on a static ip address (otherwise, how is Cloud SQL supposed to know where to replicate from?).